# How can I merge two associative arrays that are being looped?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, while-loop, db2

I am trying to run two queries from the database. I need the two queries to create an array with the same column names and then merge the two arrays together.

Here are my two queries:

```
## Order History
$q47 = "SELECT OCODT AS COMPDT, ORDNO AS ORDER, ORQTY AS OQTY, 
               QTYRC AS RQTY FROM AMFLIBP.MOHMST WHERE FITEM='$id' AND FITWH='$wh'";
$stmt47 = db2_prepare($con, $q47);
$result47 = db2_execute($stmt47);

$q48 = "SELECT DOKDT AS COMPDT, ORDNO AS ORDER, QTYOR AS OQTY, 
               DKQTY AS RQTY, VNDNR AS VNDR FROM AMFLIBP.POHISTI 
        WHERE ITNBR='$id' AND HOUSE='$wh'";
$stmt48 = db2_prepare($con, $q48);
$result48 = db2_execute($stmt48)
```

I want to do a while statement on both of the queries.

So, something that looks like this:

```
while($fin47 = db2_fetch_assoc($stmt47));

and

while($fin48 = db2_fetch_assoc($stmt48));
```

After the while statements have been completed,

I want to take the results from both of the while statements and 
put them in to an array sorted by `COMPDT`.

I have tried doing this:

```
## Order History
$q47 = "SELECT OCODT AS COMPDT, ORDNO AS ORDER, ORQTY AS OQTY, QTYRC AS RQTY 
        FROM AMFLIBP.MOHMST 
        WHERE FITEM='$id' AND FITWH='$wh'";

$stmt47 = db2_prepare($con, $q47);
$result47 = db2_execute($stmt47);
while($fin47 = db2_fetch_array($stmt47));

$q48 = "SELECT DOKDT AS COMPDT, ORDNO AS ORDER, QTYOR AS OQTY, DKQTY AS RQTY, 
               VNDNR AS VNDR FROM AMFLIBP.POHISTI 
        WHERE ITNBR='$id' AND HOUSE='$wh'";

$stmt48 = db2_prepare($con, $q48);
$result48 = db2_execute($stmt48);
while($fin48 = db2_fetch_array($stmt48));

$array = array_merge($fin47, $fin48);
print_r($array);
```

From the `print_r($array);`

I get nothing but the following error in my `php.log`:

```
[29-Dec-2013 09:17:03 Antarctica/Mawson] PHP Warning:  
array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in 
     /www/zendsvr6/htdocs/views/test.php on line 42
```

I know the while statements are causing the problem cause I've done array_merge's before. 
It's something with my syntax. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

ADDED INFORMATION:

By doing this:

```
## Order History
$q47 = "SELECT OCODT AS COMPDT, ORDNO AS ORDER, ORQTY AS OQTY, QTYRC AS RQTY 
        FROM AMFLIBP.MOHMST WHERE FITEM='$id' AND FITWH='$wh'";

$stmt47 = db2_prepare($con, $q47);
$result47 = db2_execute($stmt47);
while($fin47 = db2_fetch_array($stmt47))
{var_dump($fin47);}
```

I get:

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(7) "1090225" [1]=> string(7) "M703760" 
           [2]=> string(6) "20.000"     
           [3]=> string(6) "20.000" } array(4) { [0]=> string(6) "960614" 
           [1]=> string(7) "M802110"     [2]=> string(7) "340.000" 
           [3]=> string(4) ".000" }
```

Also, When I try what was suggested bellow:

```
$q47 = "SELECT OCODT AS COMPDT, ORDNO AS ORDER, ORQTY AS OQTY, QTYRC AS RQTY 
        FROM AMFLIBP.MOHMST WHERE FITEM='$id' AND FITWH='$wh'";

$stmt47 = db2_prepare($con, $q47);
$result47 = db2_execute($stmt47);
while($fin47 = db2_fetch_array($stmt47))
{$array[] = $fin47;}
print_r($array);
```

I get this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1090225 [1] => M703760 [2] => 20.000 [3] => 20.000 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [0] => 960614 [1] => M802110 [2] => 340.000 [3] => .000 ) )
```

Which works but loses my column names?

Comment: It seems the only way I can get an ouptut from either is by doing the dump withing the while statement

Comment: Yes, the `while` runs until `db2_fetch_array` returns false; which will be the final content of your `$fin47`/`48` variables. You are not assembling a list there. Also you aren't utilizing the prepare/execute step, but interpolate variables. Thirdly you could probably accomplish your goal in SQL already with a `UNION`.

Comment: Mario... I cant do this from sql because of code I didnt show in between the two queries. $id and $wh are different values.

Comment: Output of $fin47 is array(4) { [0]=> string(7) "1090225" [1]=> string(7) "M703760" [2]=> string(6) "20.000" [3]=> string(6) "20.000" } array(4) { [0]=> string(6) "960614" [1]=> string(7) "M802110" [2]=> string(7) "340.000" [3]=> string(4) ".000" } by doing

    $q47 = "SELECT OCODT AS COMPDT, ORDNO AS ORDER, ORQTY AS OQTY, QTYRC AS RQTY FROM AMFLIBP.MOHMST WHERE FITEM='$id' AND FITWH='$wh'";
    $stmt47 = db2_prepare($con, $q47);
    $result47 = db2_execute($stmt47);
    while($fin47 = db2_fetch_array($stmt47))
    {var_dump($fin47);}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
while($fin47 = db2_fetch_array($stmt47));
```

is overwriting each value of `$fin47` with the next row from your `SELECT`. What you should have done is:

```
$fin47 = array();
while($fin47[] = db2_fetch_array($stmt47));
```

However, this seems a needlessly complex way to do things. You can extract your data in the form you want with one query, meaning all your PHP code is not required.

```
$fin47 = array();
$query = "SELECT OCODT AS COMPDT, ORDNO AS ORDER, ORQTY AS OQTY, QTYRC AS RQTY, null as VNDR FROM AMFLIBP.MOHMST WHERE FITEM='$id' AND FITWH='$wh'".
" UNION ALL ".
"SELECT DOKDT AS COMPDT, ORDNO AS ORDER, QTYOR AS OQTY, DKQTY AS RQTY, VNDNR AS VNDR FROM AMFLIBP.POHISTI WHERE ITNBR='$id' AND HOUSE='$wh'".
" ORDER BY COMPDT";
$stmt = db2_prepare($con, $query);
$result = db2_execute($stmt);
while($fin47[] = db2_fetch_array($stmt));
```

Note: I've added a dummy value for `VNDR` in the first `SELECT` to match the number of columns for the `UNION`. In the resulting array these will appear as null values.

Comment: OP hinted at changing the values of `$id` and `$wh` between both queries; so maybe `db2_execute($stmt, array($id, $wh, $id48, $wh48))` even.

Comment: Also, with your first tip, the column names are not kept from the SQL statement.

Comment: Sorry - I ran this in MySQL where `null` columns are legal. You can substitute any value there that will work for you. You could use  `SELECT ..., '' as VNDR ...`, or `cast(NULL as varchar(128)) as VNDR,` (change the size of `varchar()`)

Comment: @AJBirone `db2_fetch_assoc()` will preserve column names. I just copied your original code.

Answer (score 1):

This loop will overwrite your variable on each run. It won't collect the rows. And in the last run it will leave with `false` assigned.

```
while($fin47 = db2_fetch_array($stmt47));
```

What you ought to be doing is:

```
while($fin47 = db2_fetch_array($stmt47)) {
    $array[] = $fin47;
}
```

And in your second `while` you could append to the same array. Thus your merging becomes redundant.

Comment: I lose my column names by doing this. Look at the added section in my question... I added my output.

Answer (score -1):

What is the raw output of `$fin47` and `$fin48`?

Have you tried doing a simple `+` on the values:

```
$array = $fin47 + $fin48;
```

**EDIT** Then why not do this. I have added arrays called `$fin47_results` and `$fin47_results` and set the `while` loop in each query to add the values from `$fin47` and `$fin48` to them:

```
## Order History
$q47 = "SELECT OCODT AS COMPDT, ORDNO AS ORDER, ORQTY AS OQTY, QTYRC AS RQTY FROM AMFLIBP.MOHMST WHERE FITEM='$id' AND FITWH='$wh'";
$stmt47 = db2_prepare($con, $q47);
$result47 = db2_execute($stmt47);
$fin47_results = array();
// while($fin47 = db2_fetch_assoc($stmt47)) {
while($fin47 = db2_fetch_array($stmt47)) {
  $fin47_results[] = $fin47;
}

$q48 = "SELECT DOKDT AS COMPDT, ORDNO AS ORDER, QTYOR AS OQTY, DKQTY AS RQTY, VNDNR AS VNDR FROM AMFLIBP.POHISTI WHERE ITNBR='$id' AND HOUSE='$wh'";
$stmt48 = db2_prepare($con, $q48);
$result48 = db2_execute($stmt48);
$fin48_results = array();
// while($fin48 = db2_fetch_assoc($stmt48)) {
while($fin48 = db2_fetch_array($stmt48)) {
  $fin48_results[] = $fin48;
}

$array = array_merge($fin48_results, $fin48_results);
print_r($array);
```

If you notice I also added—but commented out—calls for `db2_fetch_assoc` since your end goal & raw dataset is unclear. But this should work.

Comment: $fin47 and $fin48 are not an actual value unless they are used inside of the while statement. So, if I put var_dump($stmt47) anywhere but inside of the while statement I get an error saying that its an undefined variable in php.log.

Comment: Check the added section in the question... I tried what you and mario said.